# Exoplayer cache not being used for playback when offline

Tags: android, caching, exoplayer

Using exoplayer 2.8.1, testing on android SDK versions 19 and 23.

I construct a cache and data source factories using the following code:

```
private static final long DEFAULT_MAX_CACHE_SIZE = 20*1024*1024L;

    cacheEvictor = new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(DEFAULT_MAX_CACHE_SIZE);

    cache = new SimpleCache(
            new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "exoplayer-cache"),
            cacheEvictor);

    uncachedDataSourceFactory = new OkHttpDataSourceFactory(
            new OkHttpClient(),
            "Android.ExoPlayer",
            null);
    dataSourceFactory =
            new CacheDataSourceFactory(
                    cache,
                    uncachedDataSourceFactory);
```

I then precache standard HTTP audio content using the following code:

```
    new Thread (new Runnable () {
        public void run() {
            try {
                CacheUtil.cache(
                        new DataSpec(uri, DataSpec.FLAG_ALLOW_CACHING_UNKNOWN_LENGTH | DataSpec.FLAG_ALLOW_GZIP),
                        cache,
                        uncachedDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(),
                        null,
                        null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                callback.invoke(false, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                callback.invoke(false, "Download interrupted");
            }
            callback.invoke(true);
        }
    }).start();
```

The callback is invoked with true, so this process seems to be completing correctly.  Following this, I disconnect from the network and attempt to play the cached content:

```
    DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);
    mediaSource =   new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .setContinueLoadingCheckIntervalBytes(128 * 1024)       // check whether to load more every 128KB
            .createMediaSource(uri);
    mediaSource.addEventListener(handler, new DefaultMediaSourceEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadError(int windowIndex, @Nullable MediaSource.MediaPeriodId mediaPeriodId, LoadEventInfo loadEventInfo, MediaLoadData mediaLoadData, IOException error, boolean wasCanceled) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "media load error for " + uri + ": " + error);
        }
    });
    player.addListener(new Player.DefaultEventListener() {
        boolean preparing = true;
        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState)
        {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "player " + uri + " state change " + playbackState + ", " + playWhenReady);
            switch (playbackState) {
                case Player.STATE_READY:
                    if (preparing) {
                        preparing = false;
                        callback.invoke(null, getInfo(player));
                    }
                    break;
                case Player.STATE_ENDED:
                    player.seekTo(0);
                    emitMessageEvent(playerId, "ended", "playback completed");
                    if (playerAutoDestroy.get(playerId)) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged(STATE_ENDED): Autodestroying player...");
                        destroy(playerId);
                    }
                    break;
                case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
                    onLoadingChanged(true);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Playback error for " + uri + ": " + error.getMessage(), error);
            emitMessageEvent(playerId, "error", "Playback error: " + error.getMessage());
            destroy(playerId);
        }
   });
   player.prepare(mediaSource, true, true);
```

When I do this, I get several media source errors, and finally a playback error in my logs:

```
06-02 11:20:52.839 32762-327/com.tackta.buxton I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init 93903d2 [ExoPlayerLib/2.8.1] [generic_x86, Android SDK built for x86, unknown, 23]
06-02 11:20:52.840 32762-327/com.tackta.buxton I/AudioPlayerModule: player http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/podpress_trac/feed/2043/0/clarkesworld_06_18_tem.mp3 state change 2, false
06-02 11:20:52.844 32762-32762/com.tackta.buxton I/AudioPlayerModule: media load error for http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/podpress_trac/feed/2043/0/clarkesworld_06_18_tem.mp3: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/podpress_trac/feed/2043/0/clarkesworld_06_18_tem.mp3
06-02 11:20:52.844 32762-32762/com.tackta.buxton I/AudioPlayerModule: media load error for http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/podpress_trac/feed/2043/0/clarkesworld_06_18_tem.mp3: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/podpress_trac/feed/2043/0/clarkesworld_06_18_tem.mp3
06-02 11:20:53.846 32762-32762/com.tackta.buxton I/AudioPlayerModule: media load error for http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/podpress_trac/feed/2043/0/clarkesworld_06_18_tem.mp3: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/podpress_trac/feed/2043/0/clarkesworld_06_18_tem.mp3
06-02 11:20:55.848 32762-32762/com.tackta.buxton I/AudioPlayerModule: media load error for http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/podpress_trac/feed/2043/0/clarkesworld_06_18_tem.mp3: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/podpress_trac/feed/2043/0/clarkesworld_06_18_tem.mp3
06-02 11:20:55.858 32762-407/com.tackta.buxton E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
06-02 11:20:55.859 32762-327/com.tackta.buxton I/AudioPlayerModule: Playback error for http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/podpress_trac/feed/2043/0/clarkesworld_06_18_tem.mp3: null
06-02 11:20:55.863 32762-327/com.tackta.buxton I/ExoPlayerImpl: Release 93903d2 [ExoPlayerLib/2.8.1] [generic_x86, Android SDK built for x86, unknown, 23] [goog.exo.core, goog.exo.okhttp]
```

Should this code be accessing the data from the preloaded cache, or is there a reason it's trying to contact the network server instead?  Is there a way of telling it to use the cache without trying to contact the server?

Comment: I'm not sure why you suggest these are duplicates? Yes, the problems are happeing with the same piece of code, but the symptoms seem entirely unrelated.  Or are you suggesting there's likely to be a single cause of both problems?

Comment: You are right. I acted too fast. I did not pay attention. I retracted my action.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be late but good to share solution with the rest of fellow developers. The code to your problem is in bellow.

```
private final String vidUrl = "https://www.TEST-SIZTE.com/videos/video.mp4";
    private void initializePlayer(){

    if (exoPlayer == null) {
        final DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultDataSourceFactory(requireContext(), Util.getUserAgent(requireContext(), getString(R.string.app_name)));

        final MediaSourceFactory mediaSourceFactory =
                new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory)
                        .setAdViewProvider(fragBinding.fullScreenVideoView);
        exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(requireContext()).setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory).build();
    }
    fragBinding.fullScreenVideoView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
    fragBinding.fullScreenVideoView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_HEIGHT);
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
    mediaContentSFun();
    exoPlayer.prepare();
}

private void mediaContentSFun(){
    final MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource();
    exoPlayer.setMediaSource(mediaSource, false);
}

private MediaSource buildMediaSource(){
    final SimpleCache simpleCache = ExoSimpleCache.getSimpleCacheInstance(requireActivity());

    final DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(requireContext(), requireContext().getString(R.string.app_name));
    final CacheDataSource.Factory cacheFactory = new CacheDataSource.Factory();
    cacheFactory.setCache(simpleCache);
    cacheFactory.setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory);

    final ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory mediaSourceFactory = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheFactory);
    final MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(vidUrl);

    final MediaSource mediaSource = mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(mediaItem);


    return new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSource);
}
```

And finally ExoSimpleCache class which needs to be used as singletone.

```
public class ExoSimpleCache {
   private static SimpleCache simpleCache;

public static SimpleCache getSimpleCacheInstance(final Context context){
    if (simpleCache == null){
        final long maxBytes = 1024L * 1024 * 1024 * 18; 
        // for 18 GB, my total needed cache size was 18GB you can change it as per your need.
        final LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor evictor = new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(maxBytes);
        final File file = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "media");

        final StandaloneDatabaseProvider databaseProvider = new StandaloneDatabaseProvider(context);
        simpleCache = new SimpleCache(file, evictor, databaseProvider);
    }
    return simpleCache;
}
```

}